# Mimic UITableViewCell selection behavior for UIView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a paging UIScrollView. Each "page" inside the scroll-view is a UIView (obviously) that can be composed out of other sub-views etc. Either the "page" as a whole or some sub-view inside the page must work as a "selectable area", so when the user "selects" this area an event (i.e. delegate event) should be triggered.

The problem is that this needs to behave logically like a UITableView/UITableViewCell selection!
So a simple tap-gesture recognizer is not what i want. I need something that is capable of recognizing/sending a `UIControlEventTouchUpInisde` event. This leads me obviously to the one possible solution of subclassing `UIControl` and handling/recognizing the stuff inside `touchesEnded:withEvent`. But this implies that my "selectable" element (i.e. view) must be a subclass of `UIControl` whih is not that generic anymore in terms of my "page" design!

So is this the most feasible approach i described above or is there something even more generic?
I'm right now interested only in nailing down the logical behavior of "selection" like UITableViewCell. The proper handling of the visual part when selecting (and deselecting) should be a breeze afterwards.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use a UITableView and simply subclassing the UITableViewCell?

Comment: Well, yes! It's a design decission. Actually the use-case fits perfectly to a UITableView (grouped style), but i wanted to achieve a different user experience. So i actually have a solution with nested scroll-views that can page vertically and horizontally, together with "page" reuse etc. -  the api is actually quite similar to UITableView.